# How do i access 'src' attribute of <img> tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_Showcase">
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="http://www.xyz.com/aaa.gif" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_loderImg" alt="Loading" /></div>        </div>
<script>
q= document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_Showcase').childNodes[1].getAttribute('src').innerHTML;

alert(q);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

how do i access 'src' attribute of img tag ? im above code it gives null value so whats wrong ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `src` on your image directly. Also, you don't need `.innerHTML`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/aU2H2/

```js
document.getElementById( 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_loderImg' ).src;
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_Showcase">
    <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_loderImg" alt="Loading" /></div>        
</div>
<script>
    q = document.getElementById( 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_loderImg' ).src;
    alert(q);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
alert(document.getElementById('your_image_id').getAttribute('src'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't use .innerHTML at the end as attributes don't have innerHTML data. Secondly, JS is very fragile with how it handles children when it comes to whitespace. I would recommend targeting the image by ID as others have pointed out. Alternatively you could use something like this:

```
q= document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_Showcase').getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
```

to reference the **ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_Showcase** node and then find the image underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

`var imgsrc = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_loderImg").attr("src");`

jQuery is the most robust way IMO.

Comment: The user not tagged the question in jquery

Comment: I'd suggest using jQuery for this kind of thing - it handles it very well

Comment: Yeah we all know the best way is jquery..i too agree..but the asker wants in javascript

Comment: jQuery is Javascript... I don't see reason for that or @Matt Wolfe's answer to get downvoted.

Comment: jQuery may be JavaScript, but not all JavaScript is jQuery. User asked for JS, not jQuery. It is clear the user is using vanilla JS to achieve this.

Comment: @duncan12 - The point is, we assume OP wants jQuery only when he tagged `jQuery`.